# Razor implementing template to wrap objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

The goal es to have a template :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-11">
      @RenderBody()
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and in normal cshtml:

```
@using ("template") {
  // Any html razor content
}

@using ("template") {
  // Other different html razor content
}
```

Is there anyway to achieve this using cshtml for templates (no c# or html writers) ?
I know it can be accomplished with partial views, but I want to avoid to create a partial view for every piece of content I want to wrap with that template.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial Views or js Templates as mustache or handlebars.
I do not think you can assign Template with razor syntax @ to another server variable inline 
you also can create Razor Helpers but if you do not want to use partialViews not sure if u want to do that

```
@helper MyTemplate(){
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-11">
  @RenderBody()
</div>
 </div>
```

}

and use it as **@HTML.MyTemplate**